# Stash multiple files

Tags: git, github

I have total 30 files and I have made changes in 15 files. Out of those files I have to make 2 stash. The first stash will have some files and in another stash, I need the other files. Also, there will be some files which I will never stash. I know how to stash single file or whole. I need the way to stash multiple files out of all

Comment: SCouto - Read the question deliberately

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do is stash all the changes, then apply the stash and checkout the files I don't need and stash again (with a name perhaps).

```
git stash save all_changes
git stash apply
git checkout <unnecessary_files1>
git stash save stash1
git stash apply all_changes
git checkout <unncessary_files2>
git stash save stash2
```

Or you could stage the changes you want to keep in stash and use `stash -k` to stash them.